# How to clear credentials associated with the OneDrive for Business sync app?

Tags: onedrive, credentials

We are using the OneDrive for business sync app to synchronize our document libraries in SharePoint with our PCs in the office.

Recently, I came across a situation when testing where I entered my *personal* Hotmail credentials instead of the *organizational* account that had permission to access a document library. I knew it was not going to work but wanted to see what would happen so I could support our users if they ever made a similar error.

As expected, my OneDrive for Business sync app was then unable to authenticate with my Office 365 account and gave me a "unable to sync" error.

Unfortunately, **nothing** I subsequently did would make the sync app forget the incorrect credentials.

After realising there was no "log out" option in the sync app itself, I went on to try the following steps:

- deleted cookies in all my browsers
- uninstalled the OneDrive for Business sync app
- deleted all registry keys that I could find that were associated with the sync app (perhaps I missed something?)
- reinstalled the sync app (problem persisted in my Windows login)

*Microsoft's SharePoint support team were also unable to resolve the issue* during a remote support session of my PC and I ended up simply restoring my PC to a previous state. This is not acceptable as it may not be an option for a user.

I can't believe Microsoft made something that should be simple so difficult. With Dropbox you can do the same thing very easily.

Does anyone know how to clear the credentials associated with a user's OneDrive for Business sync app, or at least some kind of work around that doesn't involve having to recreate the user's Windows profile or restore to a previous system state?

Comment: Have you looked in the Credential Manager on your computer?

Comment: @techie007 I checked Credential Manager but it's completely empty. Any other ideas?

Can whoever downvoted the question share what their problem with it was with the rest of us? Thanks.

Comment: I'd upvote this ten times if I could, my company recently (unfortunately) switched to OneDrive from Google Drive and its been nothing but problems.

Comment: Are you using Office 2013? If so I will suggest a work around.

Comment: In Credential Manager, there is [OneDrive Cache Credential](http://i.imgur.com/PIvfJoN.png), but this is for OneDrive Personal. For OneDrive Business, it might be listed as SharePoint. Might review your Credentials and see if it is SharePoint.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and found two sets of credentials for OneDrive in Credential Manager.  I deleted the incorrect set and rebooted.  My OneDrive now syncs to the correct library.

Comment: Where do i find "Credential Manager"?

Comment: Its a standard Windows program, just type the name in the start menu search

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use another Office App (say Word) to logout of your current account (even if Word says you are logged into your business Account). Use Start -> Account in that app to find your current login and options regarding your Office Account.

Then, after logging out, you login back again with the credentials you want (the "official ones"). After that, the Onedrive for Business sync client will re-sync your files.